# How to plot a histogram with specific ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, histogram

I have the following Dataframe;

```
items1 = ['one', 'two']
items2 = ['JR Sagami Line','JR Tsurumi Line','JR Sagami Line','JR Tsurumi Line','JR Ome Line']
items3 = ['tokyo','shizuoka','saitma','oosaka']

dict_a = {
   'log_timestamp_jst': np.random.randint(100, size=100),
   'dt': pd.date_range('2022-5-01', periods=100, freq='1d'),
   'hh': np.random.randint(10, 21, size=100),
     'uid': np.random.choice(30, 100, replace=True),
   'uid_type': random.choices(items1, k=100),
   'brand_id': random.choices(items2, k=100),
     'state': random.choices(items3, k=100),
   'shop_name': pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,  size=100),
   'shop_state': random.choices(items3, k=100),
    'visit_or_not':np.random.randint(2, size=100),
     'time_at_shop': np.random.randint(21, size=100)
 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
```

“brand_id” is the train line’name, and “uid” is the advertising identifier (tracked inside the train).

I want to plot a graph that x axis shows the number of time that a contact to advertisement happened(count of uid) ,
the x axis’ ticks should be 0, 0 to 2, more than 3

Also the y axis should be the percentage of visiting the shop(where visit_or_not==1).

Please help.

I tried these lines but it wasn't what I expect.

```
line = df[df['brand_id']=='JR Tsurumi Line']
line.uid.value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

`value_counts` will give you how many times an ads has been contacted. To show the frequency (e.g. 5 ads were seen 0 time, 7 ads were seen 1 - 2 times, etc.), you need to bin them and count again.

Use `pd.cut` to allow them to bins:

```py
s = df.loc[df["brand_id"] == "JR Tsurumi Line", "uid"].value_counts()
ax = (
    pd.cut(s, [-np.inf, 0, 3, np.inf], labels=["0", "1 - 2", "3+"])
    .value_counts(sort=False)
    .plot(kind="bar")
)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

Result:

[image]